# np.vectorize returns incorrectly rounded result

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to apply the same function to two dataframes. Both have the same row 1 but different row 0. I think that in each dataframe, in row 1, the result (D) should be the same. Any ideas why it is coming out different please?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1, 1],
                    'B' : [1, 1]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1, 1],
                    'B' : [float('nan'), 1]})

C = 0.2

def fun (A, B):
    if math.isnan(B):
        return 1
    else:
        return A + C / B

df1['D'] = np.vectorize(fun)(df1['A'], df1['B'])
df2['D'] = np.vectorize(fun)(df2['A'], df2['B'])
```

[image: DF]

Comment: It's better to use the vectorized fucntions when possible, instead of rolling out your own, because they won't get faster. Especially for a function like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should seek to vectorise wherever possible. For example, the best way of doing this is with

```
df2.A + .2 * df2.B

0    NaN
1    1.2
dtype: float64
```

Or, still better,

```
np.where(df2.B.isna(), 1, df2.A + .2 * df2.B)
array([1. , 1.2])
```

---

Assuming this is a stand-in for a more complex function, the reason for this is because of a `dtype` mismatch issue... the return value is truncated to `int`. Try passing an `otypes=[float]` parameter to `vectorize` to specify a return type of `float`.

```
f = np.vectorize(fun, otypes=[float])
f(df2['A'], df2['B'])
array([1. , 1.2])

f(df1['A'], df1['B'])
array([1.2, 1.2])
```